# MUI Base Input with Adornments using hooks

Tags: input, react-hooks, material-ui, headless-ui

I want to use hooks with [MUI Base Input](https://mui.com/base-ui/react-input/#customization). And I'd like to use startAdornment and endAdornment. The website [states here](https://mui.com/base-ui/react-input/#customization) that

> The [start adornment] features can be used with both components and hooks.

But then doesn't give an example. If I pass startAdornment as a prop to their hooks example component it doesn't work.

I want to know: should it be possible "in theory" to use startAdornment, if you implement it yourself? Or is it already supported somehow when using hooks?